# How to solve BeanDefinitionStoreException caused by FileNotFoundException in SPRING?

Tags: java, spring, netbeans-8

I'm trying out an activity which calls a method draw() in Triangle bean using SPRING. However, when I try to access the spring.xml file I came across with an error.

The Error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.spring.application.SpringApplication.main(SpringApplication.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

Here is main which is the SpringApplication.java :

```
package org.spring.application;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringApplication
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("Triangle");
        triangle.draw();
    }

}
```

Here are the code in the spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
        <bean id="Triangle" class="org.spring.application.Triangle"/>
</beans>
```

And here is the Project Folder:
[Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7asSO.png)

I'm using NetBeans IDE. I also included the Spring Library and Components Logging.
Can someone help me and point out if I'm doing something wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the package. `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");` should be `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("org/spring/application/spring.xml");`

Answer (score 0):

You should place your `spring.xml` in the resource folder.
Use the following structure:
[image]